# How to save cell address in a loop

Tags: vba, loops, save, location, cell

I have a spreadsheet full of zeros, but some cells have values. These values indicate an error and I would like to know where these errors are located. This is my spreadsheet:

[My spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj2xy.png)

This is my code:

```
Sub FindErrors()

Worksheets("Realisering Flow - aggregeret").Activate

For Each c In Range("EC3:IX1372").Cells
  If c.Value <> 0 Then
    Value = c.Value
    Address = c.Address

    MsgBox "Der er fundet fejl i celle " & Address & _
       "; som har værdien " & Value
  End If

Next

Worksheets("OPS_Volume").Activate

MsgBox "Der er ikke nogen fejl"

End Sub
```

Right now I get a msgbox for each error, but I would like a list of all the errors in a different spreadsheet, but I dont how to save the address in a loop. Also I would like to save the header for the column of the Error.

I hope someone can help me - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub FindErrors()
Dim myArray() ' declare array as dynamic so we can adjust its size later
ReDim myArray(2,0) ' redim it so it's 2 dimensional
With Worksheets("Realisering Flow - aggregeret")

    For Each c In .Range("EC3:IX1372").Cells
        If c.Value <> 0 Then
            Value = c.Value
            Address = c.Address
            Header = .Cells(1, c.Column).Value

            'MsgBox "Der er fundet fejl i celle " & Address; som har værdien " & Value
            myArray(0, UBound(myArray,2)) = Value
            myArray(1, UBound(myArray,2)) = Address
            myArray(2, UBound(myArray,2)) = Header
            ReDim Preserve myArray(2, UBound(myArray, 2)+1) ' increase size of array by 1
      End If

    Next
End With

Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Worksheets("OPS_Volume").Range("A1") ' point Range to A1
' Now push the array into OPS_Volume starting from A1 (adjust Destination as necessary) 
Destination.Resize(UBound(myArray, 2)+1, UBound(myArray, 1)+1).Value = myArray
'MsgBox "Der er ikke nogen fejl"

End Sub
```

The above code will gather the details you are asking for in a 2 dimensional array, then output that array back onto the second worksheet you have in the Sub.  You can amend where it outputs the array to easily enough; let me know if there's anything in here you didn't understand?

Comment: Thank you Dave - it almost works perfectly. I cant get the part with the header to work, but if I comment that part out it works like a charm. 

I get this error: 

[Error for the header][1] 


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XguPW.png

Thanks for taking time to help me!

Comment: My mistake, specified it in a `Cells` format when it was a `Range`.  Have sorted this now in the above code, one quick change and you should be good to go

Comment: Hi again :) I dont get an error on the Header anymore, but the output still dont contain the Header, but only the value and the cell address. When I run the code stepwise I can see the myArray contains the Header, but not when it is pushed into the other spreadsheet.

Comment: Amended the `Resize` command.  It takes numbers of rows and columns to set up, and since the array's dimensions are indexed from zero, they need to be incremented by one to capture all the columns and rows properly